# Correctly appending and reading arrays x86 MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm trying to get the results from a calculation all in an array and then read the entire array out at once. I've got the calculation part all set:

```
include Irvine32.inc

.data
oCount DWORD 1
iCount DWORD ?
lower DWORD 0
results DWORD 25 DUP(?)
.code
main PROC
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,25
L1:
    mov oCount, ecx             ;Store the Outer Count
    mov ecx, ebx                ;Put the inner count in the limit register
    mov iCount, ebx             ;Put the inner count in the iCount variable
    mov ebx, 0                  ;reset ebx register to 0
    L2:
        add ebx,iCount          ;adds the current value(in iCount)to the total(ebx)
        Loop L2     
    mov eax, ebx                ;moves the upper to eax
    sub eax, lower              ;subtracts the lower from eax
    mov ebx, iCount
```

So right here at this part I have the correct number on each iteration. I now need to add the value from eax into the previously declared results array

```
    mov results[ebx], eax
```

The logic I am trying to use here (which is incorrect) is that I will add eax to the results, using ebx as an iterator. I've also tried multiplying ebx so that my iteration is equal to the byte size of a DWORD to no avail. My first question is simply what am I missing here. I'm pretty sure I know what I'm *supposed* to be doing, but I just can't get it in MASM syntax

```
call WriteDec
    call crlf
    mov lower, eax
    mov ebx, iCount             ;Move iCount to ebx. This restores the innercount
    inc ebx                     ;Increase the inner count by one
    mov ecx, oCount             ;Put the outer count back in the loop counter
    Loop L1
mov eax, [results]
call WriteDec
```

At this point I'm just testing printing out one of the values from the array, but seeing as my array implementation is definitely wrong, it won't print out what I want. The program then ends:

```
call WaitMsg
invoke ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Seriously don't use the `loop` instructions for both loops; you're making things hard for yourself.  Use `dec esi / jnz L1` or something for the outer loop.  Or even `dec oCount / jnz L1`, but you have enough registers to avoid keeping your loop counter in memory.

Comment: If you want to *add* the result to the array, use `add result[ebx*4], eax`.  If you want to do a write-only store, then use `mov result[ebx*4], eax`.  (Memory addressing is always in bytes.  Nothing will ever scale by the type width for you in asm, you have to do that yourself explicitly.)